# bad signature "dash-2.12.0.tar.sig"

Tags: init-file

I am getting the following error while startup

```
Failed to verify signature dash-2.12.0.tar.sig:
No public key for 066DAFCB81E42C40 created at 2019-09-21T23:24:49+0530 using RSA
Command output:
gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir `c:/Users/sreekumar.14CPU0014/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg'
gpg: Signature made Sat Sep 21 23:24:49 2019 IST using RSA key ID 81E42C40
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
```

I don't know what is the reason and how to correct it?

**Updated part of init file**

```
   (require 'package)
   (add-to-list 'package-archives
        '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
   (add-to-list 'package-archives
        '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
   (add-to-list 'package-archives
        '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
   )
```

Comment: Bisect your init file to see which part causes the problem. Narrow your question to cover only that part. Show the problematic code.

Comment: Please see the updated `.init` file.  I am fetching packages from three repositories.

Comment: You get that error only when you have all of that in your init file - all 3 packages?

Comment: I think so. But not sure.

Comment: Bisecting should tell you that. If you add all 3 packages you can't easily know.

Comment: I think it is an `https` and `proxy` problem. When I added `(setq package-check-signature nil)`, to my `.emacs` file, the error disappeared.

Comment: If you think you've found an answer then please consider either posting that answer (you can accept your own answer) or, if you think the Q&A won't help others then perhaps delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to the GPG key update for the ELPA archive: new packages are signed with the new key.

## Solution 1

Download the package `gnu-elpa-keyring-update`. This will install the public key for `066DAFCB81E42C40`, which you are missing.

## Solution 2

Upgrade to at least Emacs 26.3, which comes with the new GPG key.